# Complete C++11 support on Android

Tags: android, c++11, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I'm currently trying to cross-compile a cross-platform library I have previously developed in order to use it on Android.
To do so, I use the arm-linux-androideabi-g++ (4.9) compiler provided by the NDK, and I link the gnu-libstdc++ also present in the NDK.

Unfortunately, the compilation won't succeed due to the use of some C++11 features.
Such features are specific methods present in "string.h" like std::to_string or std::stof, which could be replaced easily by other ones if I have to.
But I also use more complex ones, like things from "future.h" such as std::future and std::async.

I've located the reason of the compilation error for "string.h", in the file "ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/bits/basic_string.h", the following statement returning false (_GLIBCXX_USE_C99 isn't defined):

```
 //basic_string.h 

 #if ((__cplusplus >= 201103L) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99) \
     && !defined(_GLIBCXX_HAVE_BROKEN_VSWPRINTF))

 //methods I want to use

 #endif
```

From what I understood, these restrictions are induced by the Android Bionic libc.

What options do I have to solve this ?

I already tried to use the CrystaX NDK, but it only solves my "string.h" problem, and I would rather find a more standard solution.

How about using an ARM cross-compiler which isn't specific to Android ?

Thanks.

Comment: I've replied to you into [android-ndk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/6NjpXqr7QWQ) group, but it works with huge lag today, so my answer still not appeared there. Regarding <future.h> - could you say more detailed what's wrong? There should no be problem preventing its usage, so it's either mistake on your side or bug in CrystaX NDK. If it's bug, we'd be happy to fix it, so please let me know what exactly wrong. BTW, you can use our [bug tracker](https://tracker.crystax.net/projects/ndk) to file tickets and we'll try to fix problems as soon as we could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution to this issue.

First, the use of "future.h" methods is fully supported by the gnu-libstdc++ provided by the android NDK, I just missed some inclusions allowing its usage, my bad.

Next, I've taken a deep look into my library and I've figured out that the only method actually causing compilation errors was std::to_string.
So I decided to simply override it with the following :

```
#if __ANDROID__

namespace std {
  #ifndef to_string
  inline string to_string(int _Val)
  {    // convert int to string
      char _Buf[256];
      sprintf(_Buf, "%d", _Val);
      return (string(_Buf));
  }
  #endif
}

#endif
```

I guess that if there is some other unsupported C++11 methods, it's possible to override them as well.